# Copy filtered data from an Excel sheet to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from an Excel sheet that has been filtered and paste it into a new worksheet without copying the data that has been hidden by the filter.

```vb
Sub GrabFilteredData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFiltered As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set the workbook and worksheet names
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("PricingFormatting.xlsx") ' Replace with your actual file name
    
    ' Check if the workbook is open
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        ' Set the worksheet where the filtered data exists
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data") ' Replace with your actual sheet name
        
        ' Check if any filter is applied
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            ' Set the range where the filtered data exists
            Set rngFiltered = ws.AutoFilter.Range
            
            If rngFiltered.Columns(1).SpecialCells(x1CellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
                ' Copy the visible range (excluding headers)
                Set rngCopy = rngFiltered.SpecialCells(x1CellTypeVisible).Offset(1).Resize(rngFiltered.Rows.Count - 1)
                
                ' Add a new sheet to paste the filtered data
                Set wsNew = wb.Sheets.Add
                
                ' Paste the filtered data in the new sheet
                lastRow = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
                rngCopy.Copy wsNew.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)
                
                ' Clear any existing filters
                ws.AutoFilterMode = False
                
                ' Activate the new sheet
                wsNew.Activate
                
                MsgBox "Filtered data has been copied to a new sheet."
            Else
                MsgBox "No filters applied."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "No filters applied."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Workbook not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

When I use this code I get:

> member or data member not found

Comment: Not sure where you got that code from but it has two major errors: `x1CellTypeVisible` should be `xlCellTypeVisible` (starts with XL not X1) and `x1Up` should be `xlUp` (same issue)

Comment: Also you can't resize a non-contiguous range. Use `Set rngCopy = rngFiltered.Offset(1).Resize(rngFiltered.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. As the sheet is new there is no need for `lastRow = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row` just use `rngCopy.Copy wsNew.Cells(2, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Auto-Filtered Data to a New Worksheet

- You have learned about the specific error in your comments.
- This is just a more flexible version to be used with the active sheet.
- Combining both versions, you should be able to create a version that suits your specific case.

```vb
Sub CopyFilteredData()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Filtered Data"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    
    ' Reference the active sheet (it could be a chart).
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = ActiveSheet
    
    If ssh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the name of the active sheet in a variable.
    Dim sName As String: sName = ssh.Name
    
    If Not TypeOf ssh Is Worksheet Then
        MsgBox "Sheet """ & sName & """ is not a worksheet.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the active sheet (it is a worksheet).
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    
    If Not sws.AutoFilterMode Then
        MsgBox "The auto filter in worksheet """ & sName _
            & """ is turned off.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not sws.FilterMode Then
        MsgBox "No auto filter applied in worksheet """ & sName & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the auto filter range (has headers).
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = sws.AutoFilter.Range
    ' Reference the auto filter data range (no headers).
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Attempt to reference the visible rows of the data range (no headers).
    Dim vrg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If vrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No filtered data in worksheet """ & sName & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    
    ' Reference a newly added worksheet, the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy the column widths.
    rg.Rows(1).Copy
    dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' Copy the range (including headers).
    rg.Copy dfCell
    ' Activate the destination worksheet and select the first cell.
    Application.Goto dfCell
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "The filtered data in worksheet """ & sName _
        & """ has been copied to worksheet """ & dws.Name & """.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `rg.Copy dfCell` rg not vrg ?

Comment: @CDP1802 What's the use of `vrg` without headers? If OP decides to copy/append 
 to an existing worksheet with headers, then he'll need to find the first available cell and copy `vrg`.